# How to use EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables.Extensions

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

I'm trying to use EF Core with Temporal tables - SQL Server
I found these extensions:
`EntityFrameworkCore.TemporalTables.Extensions`
Which looks very nice...

However, when I run this code:

```csharp
var allItems = context.MyModel.Between(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.UtcNow);
var listOfAllItems = allItems.ToList();
```

The second line throws
`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'MyModel'.'`

Am I doing something wrong?
Or should I add some additional settings?!

Update: When I use simple `LINQ` it works, so this example comes with results:

```csharp
var allItems = context.MyModel.ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is correct? The error is telling you that the object you are referencing does not exist in the database you are connecting to.

Comment: @The2Step Yes, I'm able to use simple LINQ and I'm getting results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this extension, which works perfectly, with no problems:

https://github.com/glautrou/EfCoreTemporalTable

So you can do the same, with the method `AsTemporalBetween`:

```csharp
var allItems = context.MyModel.AsTemporalBetween(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.UtcNow);
var listOfAllItems = allItems.ToList();
```

And it retrieves all the records (From both tables).

There are also other methods available:

> - AsTemporalAll()
> - AsTemporalAsOf(date)
> - AsTemporalFrom(startDate, endDate)
> - AsTemporalBetween(startDate, endDate)
> - AsTemporalContained(startDate, endDate)

Answer (score 0):

Temporal tables are now supported in Entity Framework Core as of EF Core 6.0 RC1.

You can get to know more about the functionality [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/).